# Session Management on different servers and differet domains with same database

Tags: laravel

I am building a site in Laravel 5, I need to manage session as something like this:
For Example. I have a site x@x.com hosting on server X and another y@y.com hosting on server Y along with database,(both server are of different countries) I need to use same database for the both site but session management is typical task for me in x@x.com as database is hosting on y@y.com. I am using Auth in laravel for authentication How that will be possible please help-.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the same database connection on both servers. You can either make a small third server just for session management or you can simply tell X server to connect to the Y server database. You will first start by setting the environment variable `SESSION_DRIVER` or the configuration property `session.driver` to: `database` or `redis` depending on what you are using. Then create a connection the config file `database.php` under `connections` property if it's a RDBMS or under `redis` if it's a redis database.

```
'connections' => [
    // ...
    'session' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('SESSION_DB_HOST'),
        'database'  => env('SESSION_DB_NAME'),
        'username'  => env('SESSION_DB_USERNAME'),
        'password'  => env('SESSION_DB_PASSWORD'),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ]
]
// Or
'redis' => [

    // ...

    'session' => [
        'host'     => env('SESSION_REDIS_HOST'),
        'port'     => env('SESSION_REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => 0,
    ],

]
```

Then in the file `session.php`, change the the value of `connection` to the name of the connection you want, `session` in this case.

Be mindful that you need to open the required ports and do some authorization process and take security measures on the host server (Y server since it has the database).

**---- Answering the comment**

Session driver is the mechanism that laravel uses to manage sessions. It can be on file, database, redis... So, when you choose the session driver in its config file and the driver is a database, you would specify a database connection for it or it will use the default database connection. So, if you create a third server and you want to use Redis as the database, you would open port 6379 (in case you're using the default redis configuration), then you create a connection in your Laravel installations. The connection in `database.php` will be like so:

```
'redis' => [

    // ...

    'my_session' => [
        'host'     => env('SESSION_REDIS_HOST'),
        'port'     => env('SESSION_REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => 0,
    ],
]
```

Then in your environment or in the `.env` you add:

```
SESSION_REDIS_HOST=xx.xx.xx.xx // the ip address  or domain of the third server
SESSION_REDIS_PORT= 6379
SESSION_DRIVER=redis
```

And finally, in you `session.php` config, you would set these values:

```
//...
'connection' => 'my_session',
```

You would do this on all Laravel installations that you want to be connected to the same session database.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable suggestion, My concept is cleared now. But Still I am stuck at the point where you have mentioned the requirement of small third server,Please explain its basic need  to me in details  and also where there is need to maintain a session configuration. As I have not used the session driver in this way yet. I have done db connection only in config. What will basically session driver does and how it will relate to the servers with sessions/cookies

Comment: Added explanation on the answer

Answer (score 0):

Laravel provides database sessions which stores sessions in database so that you can use multiple servers for your application. Have a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session#database-sessions